# Telnet connection failing via port 23 (port is open on the server)

Tags: networking, tcp, telnet

I have a Windows Domain controller and a Windows 10 Work Station set up from my VirtualBox.

I am trying to connect to the Work Station on my domain via telnet on my Windows domain controller. It gives me an error "Could not open connection to the host on Port 23"

I have verified that telnet is enabled on the Work Station and also added a new Inbound rule but nothing works, is there anything else that I need to check?

Thanks!

Comment: What network type in VirtualBox do both systems use?

Comment: The network used is NAT Network

Answer (score 0):

I would check a few things to help resolve this issue...

1.Can you ping the host machine from the DC?? If not, check that the devices are in the same IP range and subnet mask, and that because you are using a virtual environment, make sure the devices are connected to the same virtual switch.

2.I would try disabling the firewall completely on both devices temporarily to see if that makes a difference, as I'm not sure if Telnent would be blocked by default on a Domain Controller as it is an insecure protocol.

3.The last thing I would try would be to disable any anti-virus on both the machines to see if that makes a difference.